How to categorize and identify the most requested features from 1000+ GitHub issues using an LLM agent?
I have scraped over 1000+ GitHub issues from a repository using Crawlee. My goal is to segregate these issues based on their descriptions, title, number of comments and statuses. I want to identify the most frequently discussed features or issues.
There are a few challenges:

Some features or issues may be duplicates or related to one another.
Some issues might have user comments (e.g., "+1") indicating
support, and I’m unsure if I need to count these.
The current approach doesn’t return the desired results when querying the LLM just by giving entire context.

Here’s the code I’ve built using Langchain and the Google Gemini API:
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=10000, chunk_overlap=1000) 
chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text)

embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")
vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embedding=embeddings)

prompt_template = """
Answer the question as detailed as possible from the provided context, make sure to provide all the details, if the answer is not in
provided context just say, "answer is not available in the context", don't provide the wrong answer\n\n
Context:\n {context}\n
Question: \n{question}\n

Answer:
"""

llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-1.5-flash", temperature=0.3)
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"])
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff", prompt=prompt)

question="What is demanding issue?"
docs = vector_store.similarity_search(question)

response = chain.invoke(
    {"input_documents": docs, "question": question},
    return_only_outputs=True
)

Problem:

The LLM doesn’t return a reliable answer when simply querying for the "most requested issue."

I probably need to identify duplicates and categorize the issues (e.g., "Bug," "Feature Request") before proceeding.
I’m confused about how to approach counting comments like "+1" to assess user demand.


Question:
What logic or approach should I use to automatically categorize these GitHub issues (e.g., classify them as bugs, feature requests, etc.), find duplicate issues, and determine the most requested features or issues based on the total number of useful comments?
